# How do I make a Record Type bit addressable in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I have a record type that is 4 Word32.

```
data MyType = MyType {a :: Word32, b :: Word32, c :: Word32, d :: Word32 }
```

Most of the time, I want to treat this type as 4 separate Word32. However, sometimes I wish to treat it as a single stream of binary data (128 bits long, the concatenation of the 4 Word32). I know that in Python, I would write different accessor functions for this "structure", so that I could read/modify it in both ways. But this is Haskell. I am wondering how an experienced Haskeller would go about this?

Comment: I feel that perhaps I should clarify what I want. I want the ability to have a type that is basically a 128 bit (big endian, unsigned) word. However, I also want the ability to pull out a (bit 127-96), b (bit 95-64), c (bit 63-32), and d (bit 31-0). I think I can write functions for a,b,c,d, but I do not know how to create a simple 128 bit word (assuming that is how it should be done). Apologies for my lack of clarity, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really want it to be like a struct of four word32's, you might want to use strict/unpacked fields:

```
data MyType = MyType { a :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Word32
                     , b :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Word32
                     , c :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Word32
                     , d :: {-# UNPACK #-} !Word32 }
  deriving (Show)
```

Then, let's define a couple of bit-fiddling functions:

```
mask :: Bits a => Int -> a
mask count = (1 `shiftL` count) - 1

bitRange :: Bits a => Int -> Int -> a -> a
bitRange low count val = (val `shiftR` low) .&. mask count
```

Now you can just write 128-bit accessors for this type:

```
from128 :: Integer -> MyType
from128 val = MyType (bitsFrom 0)
                     (bitsFrom 32)
                     (bitsFrom 64)
                     (bitsFrom 96)
  where
    bitsFrom i = fromIntegral (bitRange i 32 val)

to128 :: MyType -> Integer
to128 (MyType a b c d) =
  foldl' (.|.) 0 [
    bitsTo a 0,
    bitsTo b 32,
    bitsTo c 64,
    bitsTo d 96
  ]
  where
    bitsTo val i = fromIntegral val `shiftL` i
```

For the `a b c d` fields, you can just use [fclabels](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels).  You can also make an fclabel bijective Functor `(:<->:)`:

```
myType128 :: MyType :<->: Integer
myType128 = to128 :<->: from128
```

Comment: Thanks, there are at least 4 to 6 things here that I don't actually understand. I will try to understand it on my own line by line. But I really appreciate you giving me another (implemented) way of doing this!

Comment: @Stephen: I'd be happy to explain any question you have about this code.

Comment: {-# UNPACK #-} and !Word32 does what exactly? Unpack appears to tell the compiler to inline the value rather than using a value constructor? If this is correct, what does !Word32 do?

Comment: foldl' (.|.) 0 ... What does the (.|.) looking thing do? I start at 0, how is it "shifting" the values so they are added appropriately?

Comment: In fclabels link, it has a $(mkLabels [''Person, ''Place]). What does the '' in front of Person or Place for, what does it mean?

Comment: I have no idea what a bijective functor is, unless it is a band name or something.

Comment: {-# UNPACK #-} is a pragma directive to the compiler, instructing it to "unpack" the word32 fields, so that they are stored directly as Word32's, just as they would be in C or C++. Normally, they would be stored with a "box wrapper" (that allows for laziness/etc.. It's not a "value constructor").  The ! prefix to the type says that the field is a "strict field" -- that it computing a `MyType` value must compute that field immediately.

Comment: `(.|.)` is the bitwise-or operator. It takes two binary numbers, and does something like a `zipWith (||)` on their bits. So `5 .|. 2` would be (binary) 101 .|. 010  and result in 111  which is 7. In short: `5 .|. 2 == 7`.  The foldl' basically takes the numbers, shifts them to their right position, and then "ors them in" to the result number.

Comment: The '' is TemplateHaskell notation used to refer to type constructors. Person and Place would refer to data constructors by those names, but ''Person and ''Place refers to type constructors of those names.

Comment: @StephenCagle let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1090/discussion-between-peaker-and-stephen-cagle)

Answer (score 9):

There's a class for that :-)

```
import Data.Bits

newtype MyWord128 = MyWord128 MyType

instance Num MyWord128 where
   -- implement this one

instance Bits MyWord128 where
   -- and then this one, which is what you really want
```

Check out the [documentation for Data.Bits](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/Data-Bits.html).  A complete minimal definition is to provide an implementation of `.&.`, `.|.`, `complement`, `shift`, `rotate`, `bitSize` and `isSigned` (or a few other possible combinations: see the doc for details).  Annoyingly you also have to implement `Num`, although it's not entirely clear to me why they defined it that way.

Comment: Glomming onto this question, because I've run into it before: how would you efficiently implement, say, shift and rotate? More precisely, I would really like to be able to say 'get the Word32 at position N', which in C would be a simple pointer offset, but in Haskell I see no alternative to writing a case statement, which is not so hot. (Or using arrays, which are not fixed-size and have other overhead.)

Comment: You do no have to use a newtype MyWord128, you could just make MyType an instance of Bits.  Whether this is "efficient" is another story.  Implementing MyType on top of Storable and using raw memory plus some FFI to C code could be the most efficient way.

Comment: Re: newtype.  I am experimenting lately with only creating instances for the underlying basic datatype when I can think of a single unambiguous way to implement the instance.  In this case, I can think of at least two (big-endian or little-endian).  Hence the newtype.

Comment: Wow, I voted you up, but that seems like a substantial amount of work for what I want. All I really want is to be able to get a "range(startingBitIndex, EndingBitIndex)" of bits from MyWord 128. It appears though that in order to use Data.Bits, I would have to implemement the entire minimal definition of Num and Data.Bits? Is this correct?

Comment: For that matter, is it possible to just easily create a 128 bit word. If I had this, I could just write a set of four functions that would let me pull out a,b,c,d? Might be a lot easier?

Comment: @StephenCagle: The [Crypto library](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Crypto/latest/doc/html/Data-LargeWord.html) does have a Word128 datatype, unfortunately it's a fairly large dependency just for a single data type. I'm looking for a nicer way of getting Word128 myself. Perhaps a Data.LargeWord library is in order ;). Alternatively, as per Peaker's answer, Integer would accomodate 128 bits easily, but it's not fixed size.